# Graphviz executables not found

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, graphviz

I'm familiar with the various threads that already exist regarding this problem.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine. I'm just trying to run the example code to draw a decision tree:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

I installed graphviz and added it as a PATH variable. 
I installed pydot (now pydotplus) after installing the python's graphviz library. 
I still get the error:

```
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like the installer isn't setting the PATH variable for you](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php), you'll need to add the installation folder of Graphviz to your PATH manually.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had added the path manually. I edited my question to add that detail. It turns out I just needed to restart my machine. It's working this morning.